# How do I load a HTML Object in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, html, string, url, uiwebview

I'm new to iPhone development and I am trying to load an HTML object into an `UIWebView`.

The issue is that when I turn the HTML data into a string, the app crashes and says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. The object is a brightcove video and I copied the embed code directly from the brightcove website, so I don't understand why it isn't working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
NSString *brightstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><object id=flashObj width=540 height=400 classid=clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000 codebase=http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0><param name=movie value=http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1 /><param name=bgcolor value=#FFFFFF /><param name=flashVars value=videoId=%@&playerID=659636031001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBM6WfpHEsDft5laXH9ASJhF&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true /><param name=base value=http://admin.brightcove.com /><param name=seamlesstabbing value=false /><param name=allowFullScreen value=true /><param name=swLiveConnect value=true /><param name=allowScriptAccess value=always /><embed src=http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1 bgcolor=#FFFFFF flashVars=videoId=%@&playerID=659636031001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBM6WfpHEsDft5laXH9ASJhF&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true base=http://admin.brightcove.com name=flashObj width=540 height=400 seamlesstabbing=false type=application/x-shockwave-flash allowFullScreen=true swLiveConnect=true allowScriptAccess=always pluginspage=http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash></embed></object></body></html>", clipid]; //<--Crashes Here

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:brightstring, 540, 400];  

[videoScreen loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
NSString *brightstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...videoId=%@&...videoId=%@&...", clipid]; //<--Crashes Here
```

You have `%@` twice in your format string, but you only pass in one argument.

I'd recommend loading the HTML from a file and using `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to fill in the video ID (using a placeholder like `${VIDEO_ID}`).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just added the second argument to the end of my brightstring and now it doesn't crash, but it also doesn't load.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the video is a flash video, and to my knowledge (and I may be wrong) but iOS doesn't support flash.  Try using another format like mp4, mpv, 3gp, etc.  For testing purposes, I would first host the .html file (if you have a hosting company, or run it locally using apache), and then access it from your phone's web browser.  If it doesn't work there, then for sure it wont work this way either.

Comment: I think you may be correct.  I just loaded the main brightcove page instead of just the video player object.  the webpage loaded fine and displayed the video player object.  However, when I click the video it doesn't play in the webview but instead plays in the ios videoplayer which i believe plays mp4.